# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.<init>(Z)

Tags: websphere-8, java-bytecode-asm

I am using websphere 8.5.5 and keep on getting below exceptions.

1. Using hibernate-3.2.6.ga.jar
2. cglib-nodep-2.1_3
3. Tried multiple combination of asm jar files.. nothing worked
4. Spring 2.0.2 version Jar files

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.<init>(Z)V
```

Comment: Did you try to set Parent Last classloader in your web module? Spring 2.x is extremely old, try to upgrade.

Comment: it's working in production but somehow my local is not working.. I tried to change class loader policy as well

Comment: @Gas The ASM included in WebSphere should not be visible to applications, so parent last should not be required.  APARs have been taken to fix that in the past (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM71336).

Comment: @Nikhil Can you show more stack traces?  Which specific versions of ASM have you tried?  You have to go back to ASM 1.5.3 to get ClassWriter with a boolean parameter.  It sems you're using a very old technology stack, and you might consider upgrading.

Comment: The signature `<init>(Z)V` of the error denotes a constructor with a `boolean` parameter and [as you can see](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#constructor.summary), `ClassWriter` has no such constructor. The question is, who is trying to access such a constructor and why.